# Plotting a Heat map using x, y and z arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, contour

I have a data set that consists of:

```
x = [ 4.e-06  4.e-06  4.e-06  4.e-06  4.e-06  4.e-06  4.e-06  4.e-06  4.e-06
  3.e-06  3.e-06  3.e-06  3.e-06  3.e-06  3.e-06  3.e-06  3.e-06  3.e-06
  2.e-06  2.e-06  2.e-06  2.e-06  2.e-06  2.e-06  2.e-06  2.e-06  2.e-06
  1.e-06  1.e-06  1.e-06  1.e-06  1.e-06  1.e-06  1.e-06  1.e-06  1.e-06
  0.e+00  0.e+00  0.e+00  0.e+00  0.e+00  0.e+00  0.e+00  0.e+00  0.e+00
 -1.e-06 -1.e-06 -1.e-06 -1.e-06 -1.e-06 -1.e-06 -1.e-06 -1.e-06 -1.e-06
 -2.e-06 -2.e-06 -2.e-06 -2.e-06 -2.e-06 -2.e-06 -2.e-06 -2.e-06 -2.e-06
 -3.e-06 -3.e-06 -3.e-06 -3.e-06 -3.e-06 -3.e-06 -3.e-06 -3.e-06 -3.e-06
 -4.e-06 -4.e-06 -4.e-06 -4.e-06 -4.e-06 -4.e-06 -4.e-06 -4.e-06 -4.e-06]
and
y = [ 4.e-06  3.e-06  2.e-06  1.e-06  0.e+00 -1.e-06 -2.e-06 -3.e-06 -4.e-06
  4.e-06  3.e-06  2.e-06  1.e-06  0.e+00 -1.e-06 -2.e-06 -3.e-06 -4.e-06
  4.e-06  3.e-06  2.e-06  1.e-06  0.e+00 -1.e-06 -2.e-06 -3.e-06 -4.e-06
  4.e-06  3.e-06  2.e-06  1.e-06  0.e+00 -1.e-06 -2.e-06 -3.e-06 -4.e-06
  4.e-06  3.e-06  2.e-06  1.e-06  0.e+00 -1.e-06 -2.e-06 -3.e-06 -4.e-06
  4.e-06  3.e-06  2.e-06  1.e-06  0.e+00 -1.e-06 -2.e-06 -3.e-06 -4.e-06
  4.e-06  3.e-06  2.e-06  1.e-06  0.e+00 -1.e-06 -2.e-06 -3.e-06 -4.e-06
  4.e-06  3.e-06  2.e-06  1.e-06  0.e+00 -1.e-06 -2.e-06 -3.e-06 -4.e-06
  4.e-06  3.e-06  2.e-06  1.e-06  0.e+00 -1.e-06 -2.e-06 -3.e-06 -4.e-06]
and 
z = [[-1.51449500e+23 -1.38106793e+15 -1.38106793e+15 ... -1.38106793e+15
  -1.38106793e+15 -1.38106793e+15]
 [-1.66499269e+15 -1.51449500e+23 -1.66499269e+15 ... -1.66499269e+15
  -1.66499269e+15 -1.66499269e+15]
 [-2.00000000e+15 -2.00000000e+15 -1.51449500e+23 ... -2.00000000e+15
  -2.00000000e+15 -2.00000000e+15]
 ...
 [-2.49999997e+17 -2.49999997e+17 -2.49999997e+17 ... -1.51449500e+23
  -2.49999997e+17 -2.49999997e+17]
 [-1.99999999e+18 -1.99999999e+18 -1.99999999e+18 ... -1.99999999e+18
  -1.51449500e+23 -1.99999999e+18]
 [-1.99999999e+18 -1.99999999e+18 -1.99999999e+18 ... -1.99999999e+18
  -1.99999999e+18 -1.51449500e+23]]
```

Here x and y both have a size of 81 and z has a size of (81,81). I was wondering how to make a heat map of this. Currently I have  contour plot that looks like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(x, y, z, 50)
```

[Contour plot of x,y,z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhByX.png)

I was looking to use a heatmap instead here because the contour plot is messy and you can't see what's going on. A top down view of this plot could work as well with a colour bar on the side to show the magnitude in the z direction.

Comment: Did you try `ax.pcolor(x, y, z[:-1,:-1])`? Or `ax.imshow(z.ravel(), extent=[x0,x1,y0,y1], origin='lower')?`